# How do I show an image using Gtk.jl?

Tags: gtk, julia

I am trying to use Gtk to show an image. I used this code:

```
using Gtk

win = GtkWindow("My First Gtk.jl Program", 400, 200)

a = GtkImage("image.jpg")

push!(win, a)
```

But it does not work:

[image: image containing my code and respective output: a blank Gtk window with a warning symbol in the center]

Comment: Hey, can you try using the full/absolute path to the image?

Comment: dont wored @logankilpatrick

Answer (score 0):

You may need to make the image itself display with show(a). In addition, if you are running outside the REPL, the program may close before you see the window.  Adding readline() to the end of the program can check this, and there is a section at the end of the documantation of Gtk that suggests

```
if !isinteractive()
    c = Condition()
    signal_connect(win, :destroy) do widget
        notify(c)
    end
    wait(c)
end
```

rather than readline().